# WebDriver cannot open any SalseForce app page without login

Tags: selenium, webdriver, salesforce, selenium-chromedriver

**Used Tools:**
ChromeDriver: v. 2.46, 
Chrome: v.  45.0.2454

**Scenario:**

1. Log in to the salesforce.com
2. Check that you are on Home page.
3. Switch to the next page

**Problem:**

When I go to salesforce.com and login manually, I can go to any page without any other logins. When ChromeDriver opens the browser and logs in, any other page requires login.

a) I tried to launch the browser with the options:

```
 var options = new ChromeOptions();
 options.AddArgument("--enable-automatic-password-saving");
```

b) I tried FirefoxDriver, but the result is the same.

Please help me resolve this issue. Thank you.

Comment: what language are you using?

Comment: Can you show us the complete code you have so far (without the real credentials please)? Thanks.

Comment: It is good if you share your sample code, that will help us to debug logic and issue

Answer (score 0):

thank you very much for your replies. The solution appeared to be pretty interesting. I have specified the app url for the WebDriver to login in this format:

https://login.salesforce.com/?un=username@domain.com&pw=your_password

and it solved the problem.